# SQL ORA-00933 command not Properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am pretty new to SQL I hope you can help.

I have inherited some script from a colleague. Who is no longer around to ask.

I am getting ORA-00933 command not Properly ended

Error at line: 13 Column: 96

See pic of error below

[image]

My code is below. Any help is as always greatly appreciated.

CODE

```
(select coalesce ("DTOVS".MDM_DMN_GEO_CD,"ITOVS".MDM_DMN_GEO_CD)as "MDM_DMN_GEO_CD" 
,coalesce("DTOVS".info_src_cd,"ITOVS".info_src_cd) as "INFO_SRC_CD"
,coalesce("DTOVS"."Total DToVs"+"ITOVS"."Total IToVs","DTOVS"."Total DToVs","ITOVS"."Total IToVs",0) as "TOTAL TOVS" from 
(select count(distinct src_party_id) as "Total DToVs", MDM_DMN_GEO_CD,Info_src_cd from efpia.cust_expns
    where HDD_STATUS_CD='N' and expns_dt<TO_DATE('01/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') group by MDM_DMN_GEO_CD,Info_Src_Cd) "DTOVS"
full outer join
(select count(distinct src_party_id) as "Total IToVs", MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.MDM_DMN_GEO_CD,MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.Info_src_cd 
from efpia.MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS 
inner join EFPIA.MTNG on (MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.SRC_MTNG_ID=MTNG.SRC_MTNG_ID and MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.MDM_DMN_GEO_CD=MTNG.MDM_DMN_GEO_CD
    and MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.INFO_SRC_CD=MTNG.INFO_SRC_CD)
where MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.HDD_STATUS_CD = 'N' and MTNG_STRT_DT < TO_DATE('01/01/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')
group by MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.MDM_DMN_GEO_CD,MTNG_BDGT_EXPNS.Info_Src_Cd)  "ITOVS"
on ("DTOVS".MDM_DMN_GEO_CD="ITOVS".MDM_DMN_GEO_CD and "DTOVS".Info_src_cd="ITOVS".info_src_cd)) "TOTAL"
```

I think the error is happening on this line

```
on ("DTOVS".MDM_DMN_GEO_CD="ITOVS".MDM_DMN_GEO_CD and "DTOVS".Info_src_cd="ITOVS".info_src_cd)) "TOTAL"
```

But i cant be sure :-)

Comment: Is this the entire code? It seems an extract from a more complex statement; if so, please post the complete statement

Comment: This is the entire code that I have. As I said I just inherited this from a former colleague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a part of code? Because if it's not you don't need first `(` and delete from the end of script - `) "TOTAL""`

Comment: @ Leo: Thank you I deleted "TOTAL" from the end and it worked.